# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful resources for both the GM and the player
- utilities for running meets online
- the site's twitter account
- cool roleplaying events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5288).

Comment: Would someone be willing to work up a "be nice" ad for the site?

Comment: @C.Ross I made a cheesy one, below.

Answer (score 38):

[image: Rolling Made Awesome!]

Comment: This slogan is hilarious.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Roll20 - Virtual tabletop gaming that tells a story]

Answer (score 25):

[image: Great RPGs have great worlds!]

Comment: Hello.  Someone from our site submitted this ad to you late in 2014 so I popped over to resubmit for the new year.  I'm a mod on Worldbuilding and I sometimes read RPG but I haven't really "been" here; hope this is ok.

Comment: Tis! I know a couple of us are big fans of WB even though we're not very active.

Comment: Thanks @KRyan!  I enjoy RPGs too but haven't stayed current (haven't played anything in a few years because, well, time mainly).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Join Mythology Stack Exchange and meet the original dungeon crawler]

Comment: Haha, nice slogan for our site. +1

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks. We are trying to tailor these to the target site's audience, glad to see our effort is appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

[image: MapTool – For the RP Games you play]

Comment: Was popular last year

Comment: Also super awesome virtual table software.  +1ed.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Community Promotion Ads - 2015]

Answer (score 10):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/rpg.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Like the idea, but your format does not appear to match the requirements.

Comment: @KRyan: If you mean the size, that's not a problem; see [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884).

Comment: Ah, in that case, +1.

Comment: @KRyan [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/152515), this just magically happens and we can use whatever multiples of the standard dimensions we want. :D

Comment: This is awesome! Any chance you could adjust the code to special-case the result of 1 to switch are/is and bounties/bounty?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Please ask the original author: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin

Comment: This is incorrect. There are currently two bounties with each 150 reputation, but this script shows 1 bounty for 150.

Comment: @MarcDingena: Please take this up with the author; see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin

Comment: Crap... to get a screenshot of the page I gotta keep hitting refresh for the rest of the afternoon I think.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Scabard is a free web-based RPG campaign manager]

Comment: Keep track of PC, NPCs, adventure logs, maps, guilds, etc. for your RPG campaign

Comment: This ad's target site ([www.scabbard.com](http://www.scabard.com/)) is currently giving a 503 error.

Comment: Thanks @BESW. Our server was running out of memory yesterday, and it's been since upgraded. The site (www.scabard.com) is working again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Edgerunner Alpha - Fate-Powered Cyberpunk Roleplaying]

Comment: This ad would benefit from having a description of what the game is for. Is this some kind of dystopian sci-fi RPG or something? What's it about? What ought to grab me about playing it? What kind of stories would I tell in it? I get there's the slogan there, but there's so much space in which to say a bit more about it. See other ads above: Anydice, Roll20, Scabard, Masterplan, all tell me plainly what they are, and Maptool sounds like what it is.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Speak Friend and Enter; don't forget to Be Nice]

Comment: Other possible link-through targets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnT7pT6zCcA

and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback

Comment: While the idea of the link is nice, the quality of the graphics isn't of very high standard.  Were it better, I'd have up-voted it.

Comment: “Eye-searing” doesn't really say to me “Be Nice”.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Comment: This is really low-contrast due to the red overlay, to the point of washing out even the site's logo. It would probably be better with no red overlay and just left on a white field.