# Are our community promotion ads working as described?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

According to the [community ads thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5288/15469), ads will only be shown if they reach a score of positive 6. [The ad from movies.stackexchange](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5772/15469) is at -3 (because it's an eyesore), but it just came up on the site for me (twice).

[image: movies SE ad]

No freehand circles required here, it stands out on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the ad posted to our [community promotion ads list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/community-promotion-ads-2015). That's a hot network question ad. Everything is working here by design.

Once in a while, the site will pick a random hot network question and present it in the same slot as our Community Ads. Here that one is in the SE network [hot questions list](http://stackexchange.com/questions):

> [image: Why is penny less concerned about the 'check engine' light?]

Apparently the Movies & TV ads are pretty glary though, so I've [requested an improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266038/152515) on Meta Stack Exchange.