# "Community Ads for 2021" is still featured on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Community Ads for 2021](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/community-ads-for-2021) was posted on June 17 and was initially [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). That featured tag was removed automatically on July 24th, and it was locked on August 2nd.

There's no reason for it to be featured anymore—it's locked and there's nothing we can do with it. Nevertheless it's still showing up in our **Featured on Meta** sidebar.

[image: "Featured on Meta: Community Ads for 2021"]

It looks like this might be a bug, honestly. When I say there's no reason to be featured, I also can't imagine *on a technical level* why it's still “featured on meta” either. There is some caching in the sidebar, but not *this* much. It's been a whole month since it was un-featured. It would be really weird for it to just ... stay there indefinitely.

This seems to be just our site, too. [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15880/community-ads-for-2021) and [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8330/community-ads-for-2021) both had similar timelines on their community ads posts but it's not showing up in their featured sidebar anymore.

Could a Stack staff member please take a look at this and correct whatever's keeping it there? (And would one of our diamond mods be kind enough to give someone on staff a lil poke about this?)

Comment: Related post from MSE: "[Post remains featured in the bulletin even if \[featured\] tag is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297870)"

Comment: @Medix2 Maybe it's a misplaced unit? It says the featured thing is updated only every 24 hours, but we are *not quite* 24 days out from August 2nd.

Comment: That's a compelling theory. We're definitely more than 24 days out from July 24th though!

Comment: Either I must be going mad, or the Community Ads thing must have been reappearing. It's certainly not been there all the time in the time period.

Comment: I'd definitely noticed, yesterday, that DgtS3 was the only featured meta post in my sidebar. And today I'm back to DgtS3 + the community ad 2021 post.

Comment: And I *do* see it on WB bulletin FWIW: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KczYN.png

Comment: And now I see it on Arqade and WB, but not here. I'm mostly dropping this observation to make it clear that it being gone on our site right now (or whenever you see it) does not mean this bug is resolved.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Arqade but not Worldbuilding now. Seems intermittent?

Comment: This is a long-standing issue that we've seen off and on for years - I've reported it on MSE myself in the past... Yaakov is actually poking at it currently to see if he can fix it. I'll pass this example to him to see if we can identify if it's still happening.

Comment: The fix is live but I'm still seeing this link on Worldbuilding and, while I didn't see it earlier, I do see it here currently. There are potentially three separate caches that impact what's in that bulletin. We've ruled out the bulletin's own cache as the problem, leaving the API cache and our tag engine as potential culprits. We'll... figure it out eventually and, if not, we'll refresh the two caches manually to at least remove this batch for now - please bear with us while we dig - it's a bit easier to find these issues when there's a live example.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for the update! Best of luck!

Comment: @Catija What's the time frame for reporting back to you if we still see it? (It's there right now for me)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov See my second comment - we have to do more digging before this will be fixed. :) At this point, no action is needed from you all. I'll get an update to you once I know what we've found but I'm not sure when that will be. Apologies.

Comment: @Catija Ah, I see. The vibe I got from your explanation was something like "Caching might be the issue, so it might fix itself". Thanks for keeping in touch!

Comment: Ah, I understand, @ThomasMarkov :) Caching is the problem but this is one of those weird cases where the cache seems to get stuck. These posts will stick around (or play hide and seek) for months until we force clear the cache. We're trying to figure out why they're getting stuck so that we can prevent that or at least document how to clear it when it happens. :)

Comment: OK, y'all - [this tweet](https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1433376863133523968) is about this bug, so it's been found and squashed but we're going to have to reindex the tag engine so I'll update y'all once that's done but - we shouldn't see this problem again in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369611/51) for more info and haiku.

Comment: Thank you Yaakov!